# Apt-Get Update keeps getting the same package

Tags: apt, proxy

I started an `apt-get update` on my desktop machine today and was still running after 30 minutes.

It keeps downloading from the same repository. There is a `Get` counter on each line and that keeps incrementing. I eventually aborted it.

The output I get is:

```
Get:53 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Get:54 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Get:55 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Get:56 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Get:57 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [67.8 kB]
Get:58 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Get:59 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
...
Get:8286 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]          
Get:8287 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]          
Get:8288 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]          
Get:8289 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]          
Get:8290 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]
```

I'm running this at work and we have a proxy server. I also tried it on one of the servers at work that I look after. Same result - it is stuck on the same line.

Both my desktop and servers run Ubuntu 14.04.

It might be related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/190828/425630) question, but I get the problem with `apt-get update` whereas that issue has a problem with `apt-get upgrade`

I haven't been able yet to try this at home.

Comment: It almost seems like it keeps failing to download the file and just keeps retrying. If it's possible to stop using the proxy, that might be best.

Comment: @Zacharee1 That is exactly what it did. I even found the offending file, but then suddenly it started working again. Unfortunately, I don't know why although I have a hunch. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I narrowed it down to two files:

```
http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release
http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg
```

When I started an `apt-get-update`, a number of files would appear in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`, including these two.

The list would quickly become shorter and eventually only these two files would be left.

I had a look at `http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates` and noticed that `Release.gpg` in `partial` had the same size, but file `Release` was too short.
I also noticed that these files were updated last night on the server.

The funny thing was that I could view and download file `Release.gpg` in my browser, but I could only view file `Release` in my browser: when I tried to download it ("Save File As.."), Firefox responded that it couldn't read file `/tmp/Xu4f...` and file `Release` on disk would be empty.

Suddenly, everything started working again: `apt-get update` ran to completion within a few seconds and I could download file `Release` without a problem.

The only explanation I can think of is that there was a caching issue somewhere, because these files were updated last night.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Besides that, don't forget to accept your answer after the delay of probably 2 days if I remember right is over.