# Why my ubuntu server doesnt want to upgrade today?

Tags: server, upgrade

Today, my `ubuntu-server 14.04 LTS` doesn't want to upgrade anymore.

It stayed minutes and minutes at `0%` of package downloading and then ... 1h 46min 25s later: fails.

However, the internet connection is pretty good on this VLAN, and the web applications hosted on it works as expected.

Here is the bash outpout (french lang, sorry, its the sys config...):

```
me@host:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été conservés :
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  apache2-bin apache2-data apport bash-completion bind9-host binutils
  biosdevname bsdutils comerr-dev dnsutils dpkg dpkg-dev e2fslibs e2fsprogs
  gitlab-ce grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common irqbalance
  krb5-locales krb5-multidev libbind9-90 libblkid1 libcgmanager0 libcomerr2
  libdns100 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libffi6 libfreetype6 libgnutls-dev
  libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libgnutlsxx27 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4
  libicu52 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libk5crypto3 libkadm5clnt-mit9
  libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-7 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0
  libldap-2.4-2 libldap2-dev liblwres90 libmount1 libmysqlclient18
  libpam-systemd libpng12-0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libss2
  libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libudev1 libuuid1 libxml2
  linux-firmware linux-libc-dev lshw mount mysql-client-5.5
  mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
  nginx nginx-common nginx-extras ntpdate passenger passenger-dev
  passenger-doc php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql php5-readline policykit-1
  python-urllib3 python3-apport python3-distupgrade python3-gdbm
  python3-problem-report python3-software-properties python3-update-manager
  python3.4 python3.4-minimal software-properties-common sudo systemd-services
  tzdata ubuntu-release-upgrader-core udev update-manager-core util-linux
  uuid-runtime wpasupplicant
106 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 3 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 373 Mo/443 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 48,4 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] 
373 Mo réceptionnés en 1h 46min 25s (58,4 ko/s)
E: Impossible de récupérer https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/pool/trusty/main/g/gitlab-ce/gitlab-ce_8.2.2-ce.0_amd64.deb  Somme de contrôle de hachage incohérente

E: Impossible de récupérer quelques archives, peut-être devrez-vous lancer apt-get update ou essayer avec --fix-missing ?
```

Anybody guess what can happen here ?

Comment: I assume that `Somme de contrôle de hachage incohérente` means that the file hash doesn't match. I sometimes have similar issues as well. It normally resolved itself after a few days. The best explanation I (and others) have come up with is a caching issue on some of the mirrors. See http://askubuntu.com/a/677313/425630

Comment: I generally see failures like this when the local index doesn't match the server's index.  Perform an `update`, then retry your `upgrade`.  For the most part, you often want to do these two steps together.  Update -> Upgrade.

Comment: `apt-get update` is used to re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the location(s) specified in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. An update should always be performed before an upgrade or dist-upgrade.

Comment: @lornix Yes I tried it several times without any results

Comment: @TungTran As mentionned above, I did it but no results. It is the issue, thus.

Answer (score 0):

Because the error on this package:

> https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/pool/trusty/main/g/gitlab-ce/gitlab-ce_8.2.2-ce.0_amd64.deb

I edited the apt line about `gitlab-ce`:

```
me@host:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list 
# this file was generated by packages.gitlab.com for
# the repository at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce

#deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty main
#deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

ANd then tried again:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And it worked fine.
I fact, there is a problem with the hash of this package, and it seems that it is the first one that apt-get wanna to upgrade, thus 0 bytes where downloaded for all packages.

Now I uncommented the apt line for gitlab-ce and I pray for quick fix by Gitlab