# Infinite loading package in apt-get, infinite Get. Repeatedly trying

Tags: 16.04, apt

Ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial

`apt-get update` infinite tries to get a package:

```
ams@ubuntu-ams:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
...
```

I changed the addresses of the mirrors in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` but it did not help.

The problem is not this: [apt-get is stuck at "Fetched XXKb in XXsec"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774918/apt-get-is-stuck-at-fetched-xxkb-in-xxsec)

I think no matter what kind of package is not loaded.
After `sudo apt-get clean` I do `sudo apt-get update` and another package (not `i386`) may loops.

What's going on?

The guy got the same problem: [Why is apt-get update repeatedly downloading the same Packages file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920786/why-is-apt-get-update-repeatedly-downloading-the-same-packages-file). But I don't have enough reputation to ask how he solved the problem.

And here it worked by itself: https://askubuntu.com/a/677313/746294. What I need to do to fix it and not to wait until the cache is somewhere updated?

I replaced the http to ftp and now the package just not loaded:

```
ams@ubuntu-ams:~$ sudo sed -i 's/http/ftp/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
ams@ubuntu-ams:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Get:1 ftp://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:3 ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [366 kB]
0% [1 InRelease 247 kB/247 kB 100%] [3 Packages 366 kB/366 kB 100%]^C
```

Comment: you could try a different mirror

Comment: ... or try again after an hour or two, if there there are temporary problems at the website (of the current mirror).

Comment: I tried to change the mirror and waited 2 hours. It didn't help

Comment: post your sources.list please

Comment: I've tried these addresses:
- `ru.archive.ubuntu.com`
- `archive.ubuntu.com`
- `de.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: What program package are you trying to install (I mean what program package wants this icon package)? Or is it initiated by a general update-upgrade action?

Comment: Yes, it initiated by a general update-upgrade action. After `sudo apt-get clean` I do `sudo apt-get update` and another package loops. For example, now does not get `i386`:
`Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using any (transparent) proxy severs, it may be a misconfiguration of a proxy. Try to use HTTPS mirrors to eliminate such issues.